# How to Print data in JSON format using PHP

Tags: php, json, database, printing

PHP code :

```
print_r($InformationRetrieval['KeywordExtraction'][1]);
```

Outputs :

```
Array
(
    [google] => 15
    [search] => 18
    [or] => 2
    [web] => 4
    [is] => 4
    [a] => 5
    [engine] => 2
}
```

but needs to print words that are indexes of this array eg: google, search, or, web etc..

How is it done?

Comment: You can use `array_keys` See my answer and demo further details

Comment: Your title mentions JSON. Are you looking for [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this :

```
<?php
$a = array("google" => 15, "search" => 18, "or" => 2, "web" => 4, "is" => 4, "a" => 5, "engine" => 2);

foreach($a as $key=>$value) {
   echo $key;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_keys](https://www.php.net/array_keys);

```
print_r(array_keys($InformationRetrieval['KeywordExtraction'][2]));
```

Here is a working demo: **[Demo](http://ideone.com/mT9K51)**